# COUNTIF range does not equal range

Tags: excel

The data I'm looking to get is something like this:

```
+----------+-------+
| Location | Count |
+----------+-------+
| Jungle   |     2 |
| Ocean    |     4 |
| Other    |     2 |
+----------+-------+
```

The formula for `count` should look in the data range and if a cell's data **does not** equal any of the cell data in the rest of the location column (Jungle, Ocean) it should add that to the count. It should exclude blanks.

This is the formula I tried:

`=COUNTIF(A1:H6,"<>"&E11:E12)`

Here is my example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YbqEwa3olEXMcmU-UORfe7jwyK_-AXDomp1t5iTVUaU/edit?usp=sharing

Where am I going wrong? There are 7 other instances of colours not Green or Blue therefore I would expect this result to be output. I haven't put anything in about ignoring spaces so I would expect the result to count blanks too, but I get `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use & - this would join E11 and E12 together so you would be looking for greenblue. You would need a COUNTIFS to get the three conditions

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:H6,"<>"&E11,A1:H6,"<>"&E12,A1:H6,"<>")
```

Here is a more general way of doing it

```
=COUNTA(A1:H6)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:H6,E11:E12))
```

[See this useful reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-not-equal-to-many-things)

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Thanks! But what if there was a really long list of things to be excluded? There is a great answer here which I would never have got to https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-not-equal-to-many-things

Comment: You can also do that more directly in `SUMPRODUCT` with this type of setup: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNA(MATCH(Data_range,Things,0))+0)`

Answer (score 2):

The COUNTIFS formula is your friend here. This formula should work for that cell:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:H6,"<>"&E11,A1:H6,"<>"&E12,A1:H6,"<>")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a 'does not equal OR does not equal' is that when it is not equal to one, it could be equal to the other and vice-versa. Additionally, you range to count from is 2 dimensional so you cannot use rows of criteria. Use SUMPRODUCT and individual criteria multiplied against each other.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:H6<>"")*(A1:H6<>E11)*(A1:H6<>E12))
```

Any of those three conditions that is not true is considered zero. Anything multiplied by zero is zero. 1 x 1 x 1 is 1.

For large numbers of exclusions, you will want to use an array formula (with CSE) to count them and then subtract that total from a COUNTA total of the entire range.

```
=COUNTA(A1:H6)-SUM(COUNTIF(A1:H6,E11:E15))
```

[image]